# What kind of connector is this, and how do you connect to it properly?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, connector

[image]

What kind of connector is this, and how do you connect to it properly?

These (4 standing cylinder tubes) are the output pins of a 24V linear power supply: HC24-2.4-AG.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those look like turret connectors. They're staked (crimped), screwed or soldered into holes in the board. You connect to them by soldering wires to them, either wrapped around and soldered or soldered into the hole.

You can see some examples of how to connect to them [here](https://workmanship.nasa.gov/lib/insp/2%20books/links/sections/613%20Terminals.html).

Comment: Thank you, that helps alot!

Comment: They're a bit more rounded than I'd expect, but on the other hand they look as though they're tinned rather than being plated with silver etc. for a good sliding contact. The clincher would be if there were any flash marks visible from casual manufacturing, this would be unlikely for a sliding contact.

Answer (score 9):

As well as being solderable on the outside for permanent wire connections, they look like they might accept a 2mm banana plug for testing.

Comment: Or alligator clips. :)